# Starting with tabbed metabox

Tags: metabox, wp-register-script, tabs

I need a tabbed metabox for my plugin. 
Actually they are 5 metaboxes each one in a tab.
I found these scripts:
https://speckyboy.com/10-simple-code-snippets-creating-beautiful-tabs/

Which one is best for using in meta boxes? 
It's better to have only CSS ? JS must be registered ?

I want to start testing these scripts but would like advice on where to start.

thank you

Comment: Do you mean a custom options page for your plugin?

Comment: no. I mean a meta box with tabs

Comment: Are you talking about the back end (the admin section) or the front end (the actual site)

Comment: Hi @Greeso. Thanks for your reply. 
Since meta boxes displays in back end. I thought it was obvious I was talking about back end. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've founded the best solution and used redux framework. It really provides what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to create the metabox. Then you have to add tabs to the metabox.

For the first step, to create a metabox, [here is a tutorial for you](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336). You can use that as bases for your metabox, and maybe modify it according to your needs.

For the second step, you have to add tabs to your metabox. [This question has been asked before in Stack Overflow](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5701/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-a-meta-box-have-the-tabs-like-the-categories-meta-b), and you can follow steps describe in the answer to setup your tabs.

Please remember, WordPress uses the JQuery UI Tabs widget. So you can find [examples here](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) and [detailed documentation here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/).

Hope this helps.